# Windows NPS Logs - How to decode the class (25) attribute?

Tags: windows, radius, nps, windows-ias-server

I'm wondering if there is a specific format for the "Class" attribute in Windows NPS logs.

Specifically, I'm looking at logs from Windows Server 2019 which are under %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\NPS and have the filename format of INYYMMDD.log (*e.g.* IN230317.log).

I understand the logs for the most part, especially with help from:

[Microsoft's "Interpret IAS Format Log Files"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd197432(v=ws.10)) and
[DEEPSOFTWARE's "List of ias attributes"](https://www.deepsoftware.com/iasviewer/attributeslist.html)

The part I'm having trouble understanding is the ID 25, which maps to Attribute "Class":

`25,311 1 10.10.42.17 02/26/2023 01:41:56 10438`

The IP address is the server's own and I can see a date and time but this specific log is from March 23rd, 2023. Every log line in this specific file has the same date so I suppose it could be the last time the service was started but that's just a guess.

From looking through the "Client-Vendor" attributes via the DEEPSOFTWARE site it's indicating that 311 is Microsoft, which makes sense.

While I'm writing this I looked a bit closer at the "10438" and it seems to be a unique ID for each two entries, it increases sequentially.

So perhaps I've answered my own question... except for the "1" -- does anyone know what it means? Every line seems to contain it.